# SlidesJS - "slide to" breaks code

Tags: jquery

I have a slider that behaves normally till someone plays the Youtube video - then it stops till the video finishes. Once the video is done it forwards to the next slide.

However. Once it forwards to the next slide, the animation stops completely and 
the prev/next buttons break. Does anyone have a fix??

http://adinamurch.com/vidtest.html

The fix posted in the SlidesJS Google group didn't do anything for me.

Thanks

Edit: Here's the HTML code for the slider (auto generated by Wordpress theme):

```
<div class="sText" id="textSlider"> 
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-image"><img src="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/slide-vid1.png" /></div>
        <div class="slide-text-right ">
            <div class="slide-title"><a href="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/2012/01/test-2/"> Test </a></div>
            <div id="videoDiv">Loading...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--/ .slide  -->     
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-image"><img src="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/frame_1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide-text-right ">
            <div class="slide-title"><a href="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/2011/12/for-lifes-assets/"> For Life&#8217;s Assets </a></div>
            <div class="slide-descr"><p><img src="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/assets-text.png" alt="" title="assets-text" width="204" height="77" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-261" /></p></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!--/ .slide-text  -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--/ .slide  -->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-image"><img src="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/frame_2.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide-text-right ">
            <div class="slide-title"><a href="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/2011/12/second-test/"> Store things that matter </a></div>
            <div class="slide-descr"><p><img src="http://daatsolutions.info/ditto/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/store-text.png" alt="" title="store-text" width="236" height="63" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-259" /></p></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!--/ .slide-text  -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--/ .slide  -->
</div><!--/ .sText  -->
```

I'm using the default Youtube Javascript API, with changes to this function:

```
// This function is called when the player changes state
      function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
        //updateHTML("playerState", newState);
        var slidestat = $("#textSlider").slides("status","state");
        var slidenum = $("#textSlider").slides("status","current");
        //alert(slidestat);
        if(slidenum>1) {
            $('#textSlider').slides("play");
        } else {
            $('#textSlider').slides("stop");
        }
        if(newState == 1) { //playing (3 is buffering)
            $('#textSlider').slides("stop");
            $("#textSlider").slides("slide",1); //compensates for slidesjs bug that goes 1 slide before stopping
        } if(newState == -1) { //unstarted
            $('#textSlider').slides("pause");
        } if((newState == 2) || (newState == 0)) { //paused or finished
            $('#textSlider').slides("play");
            $("#textSlider").slides("slide",2);
        } else {
            //$('#textSlider').slides("stop");
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please post the code of the buttons and also the slider so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: danwit - I've added the code I changed. All the rest of it is the default slidesjs and default youtube API stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using setTimeout() (with the number of seconds I wanted it to pause on each slide) instead of the slider's built in functions.